# How to disable script in "dot-d" (with suffix ".d") directory in /etc without deleting it?

Tags: configuration, etc

There is a lot of stuff that is configured using directories in `/etc` with `.d` suffix, which stands for "directory" and even though Unix doesn't require such suffix, it is used to avoid name clashing.

It's hard to google it. I wanted to disable one of the scripts in `/etc/update-motd.d/` and could not do it. How to disable a script in such `.d` directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends a lot on the directory and distro in question. For example:

- `update-motd.d` scripts in Ubuntu have to be executable, as the [`update-motd` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/update-motd.5) says:

  ```
  Executable  scripts in /etc/update-motd.d/* are executed by pam_motd(8)
  ```
- Files in `profile.d` in Ubuntu should have the a `.sh` extension, since `/etc/profile` contains:

  ```
  if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
    for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
      if [ -r $i ]; then
        . $i
  ```
- Files in [`sudoers.d`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/sudoers.5) shouldn't have extensions, or end with `~`:

  ```
   ...  For example, given:

       #includedir /etc/sudoers.d

   sudo will read each file in /etc/sudoers.d, skipping file names that end
   in ‘~’ or contain a ‘.’
  ```

And so on.

---

All three points also probably apply to Debian.